# Making a request to Google Cloud speech recognition using API key

Tags: typescript, authentication, web, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-to-text-api

I want to use Google SpeechRecognition service as a fallback for SpeechRecognition API, the thing is that in the docs I only see a way to authenticate using the API key.

https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/speech/recognize

It seems to me like not a secure way and is easily abused, can I authenticate using a generated temp Bearer key?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code sample to send a recognize REST request to the Speech-to-Text API.

**Input json:**

```
{
  "config": {
      "encoding":"FLAC",
      "sampleRateHertz": 16000,
      "languageCode": "en-US",
      "enableWordTimeOffsets": false
  },
  "audio": {
      "uri":"gs://cloud-samples-tests/speech/brooklyn.flac"
  }
}
```

**Curl command:**

```
curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
    https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize \
    -d @Input.json
```

**Output:**

[image]

For more information you can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/transcribe-api).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment! I use serverless lambda so Id rather not use gcloud, but in worse case scenario is this key secure to be used in webapp client side?